# Code SignIn issue while validating application with appstore

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, itunes, jwplayer

I had integrated the JWPlayer with my iOS Application and it's working well but today I tried to upload the application to the Apple Testflight I got the error regarding the "Code SignIn issue" with the JWPlayer SDK.

Also, I had tried to change the embed option with all the available options like

1. Embed & Sign
2. Do not embed
3. Embed without sign

Archives Validation

[image]

Code SignIn Issue

[image]

Steps Taken

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved this issue using a build run script.

So I'm sharing the same with you, I hope this will also work if someone faces any code signing issue while validating application, same as mine.

Here is the build run script:

1. Open your build phase
2. Click '+' and click on "New run script phase"
3. Open the run script shell and paste the below code

   ```
   # skip if we run in debug
   if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
       echo "Skip frameworks cleaning in debug version"
       exit 0
   fi

   APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

   # This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
   # removes unused architectures.
   find "$APP_PATH" -name ‘YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
   do
   FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
   FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
   echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

   EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

   for ARCH in $ARCHS
   do
   echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
   lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
   EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
   done

   echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
   lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
   rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

   echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
   rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
   mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

   done
   ```
4. If you face the issue in only one framework then just replace 'YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework' with your framework name with their extension and if you face the same in many frameworks then just replace 'YOUR_FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework' with '*.framework'.
5. Compile and Run the Project.
6. Finally, Archive and Upload the build to Testflight.

And it's done.